# Unwanted spaces between lists only on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, sass, flexbox

I have a header menu on my website and a sub menu appears when mouse hovers on the root element which I've had no problems until now, But the structure of the menu is different on Chrome and Firefox. When using Firefox, there is an extra space which doesn't appear on Chrome.

Chrome, the result I want:

[image: Chrome, the result I want]

And here is the result on Firefox, If you realize there is an extra space between menu items.

Firefox, the result should be the same as on Chrome:

[image: Firefox, the result should be the same as on Chrome]

For summary, I've tried to make a masonry view on sub-menu when I hover the header menu but did not get the result on Firefox which I want.

```css
.sf-multicolumn-wrapper {
  z-index: 1001 !important; //because .zoomConainer has 999
  display: flex !important;
  ol {
    flex: 1 !important;
    //-moz-column-gap: 1rem !important;
     li { 
      background-color: #2C2F33 !important;
      a {
        margin: 0 !important; 
        margin-bottom: 0.1rem !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="sf-multicolumn-wrapper">
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>HREF_MENU_ITEM</li>
      <li>HREF_MENU_ITEM</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: its a bad habit of using !important tags. Its not used to mark something as "important" its soley sued to overwrite other rules which means you have already a mess. It will get even messier when you try to adjust then. !important really is only a last to use emergency command.

Comment: did you try the inspector and see what creates the space inbetween? is it padding, margin or positioning that messes up the view

Comment: @tacoshy Thanks for the information, I actualy needed to override some settings which I am not able to edit because the menu originally created from a module on drupal called superfish

Comment: @RamondeVries Thanks for the comment, inspector tool doesnt show any margins or paddings for the arrea. also the width of the element is as it is, just there is space on firefox only. Also tried moz tags didnt helps

Comment: it would really help if you provide the entire html code for this section. I have troubles to reproduce the error with the code giving.